# The TypeScript compiler can't find my previosly declared variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I'm trying to create a Node.js application which will connect to a MongoDb database. I'm using TypeScript. But the following lines of code are troublesome.

```
/// <reference path="mongodb.d.ts" />
var mongo = require('mongodb');
class DefaultModel<T> {
    private db : mongo.Db;
}
```

TSC reports that: `TS2095: Could not find symbol 'mongo'.`. I don't understand why it cannot find it as it was declared just outside the class. Can you help me figure out why?

The module is declared in mongodb.d.ts as `declare module "mongodb" { /* Omitted */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TS2095: Could not find symbol 'mongo'.

You are trying to use it in the *type* delaration space : `:mongo.Db;`. And you only have it declared in the *variable* declaration space : `var mongo`

Fix: use `import` not `var`:

```
/// <reference path="mongodb.d.ts" />
import mongo = require('mongodb');
```

Comment: It makes sense, but if I use import in stead I get this: `TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out I was missing the --module "commonjs" argument for the compiler. Thank you :)